# How to Use Carbon 2 In Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, php-carbon

I am using **Laravel 5.5** and it has **Carbon version 1.27** which has no function like

1. **roundHour()**
2. **roundMinute()**

   which are added in **Carbon version 2**.

I was trying to update the Carbon version through composer but no success

How can I use Carbon's New version in my Laravel 5.5

Comment: What error do you get in composer?

Comment: From what I read on Laravel News, Carbon 2 is only available in 5.8, as it had too many breaking changes for <5.8

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Carbon update is **due in Laravel 5.8** till then the work-around is using [laravel-carbon-2](https://github.com/kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2) adapter for Laravel.

Basically, add the following dependencies to your **composer.json**:

```
{
  ...
  "require": {
    ...
    "kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0",
    "nesbot/carbon": "2.0.0-beta.2 as 1.25.0"
  }
  ...
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update
```

Comment: and find the available latest version of carbon 2 and the adapter in https://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted

Answer (score 2):

Check the latest version of carbon 2 and the latest version of adapter in https://carbon.nesbot.com/#gettingstarted, the instruction to upgrade carbon 1 to 2 is also there.